# Does Jacoco record unit test duration?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, sonarqube, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

You can run [JUnit](http://junit.org/junit4/) tests with the [Jacoco](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/) agent to produce wonderful coverage reports. (It produces an opaque `*.exec` file during the running of the unit tests).

Some tools such as [Sonar](https://www.sonarqube.org/) - read the `*.exec` file and gather data to produce reports. Sonar is able to tell Unit test duration - but I'm not sure if it gets it from this `*.exec` file.

My question is: **Does Jacoco record unit test duration?** (Regardless of whether it shows it in its generated report).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, JaCoCo does not record time.

SonarQube [reads time of execution of tests from reports generated by maven-surefire-plugin](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/4.4.0.8066/java-surefire/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/surefire/SurefireJavaParser.java#L144).

Answer (score 0):

JaCoCo knows nothing about the individual JUnit (or TestNG, etc.) tests. It knows about classes instrumented for coverage.

The JUnit test runner, however, records test execution times in the XML output files it generates (either by the Ant `junit` task or by Maven Surefire) for the test run. When using Ant, the `junitreport` task displays test execution times in the HTML report.